# Git: HEAD vs head

Tags: git

All the documentation I can find refers to `HEAD` and I've heard numerous times that it's case sensitive.Yet I'm able to do things like,

```
git log head...merge_head
```

and it works just like

```
git log HEAD...MERGE_HEAD
```

Is this due to some customization in my local setup that I'm unaware of,  or is it just an undocumented feature (maybe to discourage such practice)?

Comment: [head is different than HEAD](https://www.sbf5.com/~cduan/technical/git/git-1.shtml)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Case sensitivity depends on your system, HEAD is case-sensitive on Linux, insensitive on Windows (e.g. msysgit) an can be both on OSX depending of the file-system configuration (HFS+ is case-insensitive by default but when formatting you can also set it to case-sensitive). 
For instance, on Linux I get:

```
git log head
fatal: ambiguous argument 'head': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

While `git log HEAD` works fine.